# Where Do I find the file? ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Word.savedState

Tags: macos, library

I am not a tech person, and found this answer to fix Word closing with Mavericks?
Where do I locate and delete the file
`~/Library/Saved Application State/com.microsoft.Word.savedState`?

Answer (score 1):

- In Finder, type <kbd>Shift-Cmd-G</kbd>
- Enter/paste `~/Library/Saved Application State`
- A new Finder window will open listing the content of that folder
- Locate `com.microsoft.Word.savedState` and delete it